# Delegates in Java like in .NET

Tags: java, generic-programming

I need some advise regarding approach in Java, as the delegates are bit different than .NET one. I wold like to create some interfaces that has the same name and same method name but only thing that differ them is number of parameters. Something like [Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) in .NET

Some code samples.

What works for now is the abstract class implemented like this.

```
public abstract class AbstractValidators {

   public <T1> boolean isValid(T1 t1) {
      return false;
   }

   public <T1,T2> boolean isValid(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
      return false;
   }

  //And so one

}
```

Then in some class we can do something like this.

```
public class SomeClass {

 AbstractValidators validateStrVsInter = new AbstractValidators() {

   public <String,Integer> boolean isValid(String t1, Integer t2) { //Don't be fool by colors the String and Integer are only names of generic parameters
         return true;
   }

 };


 public void doStaff() {

   this.validateStrVsInter.<String,Integer>isValid("String", 100); // return true;

 }

}
```

That work but is not nice solution IMHO what i need is something like various interafaces that could be assigned to one..

```
 public interface IValidator<T1> {
      public boolean isValid(T1 t);
    }

 public interface IValidator<T1,T2> {
   public boolean isValid(T1 t, T2 t2);
 }
```

Some ideas ?

**EDIT:**

What the goal is ?

Very simple to have possibility to change definition

```
isValid(String t1, Integer t2) { }
```

into

```
isValid(String t1, Integer t2, Double t3) { }
```

and in invocation

```
   validator.isValid("1",2);
```

to

```
  validator.isValid("1",2, 3.0);
```

Without changing class import etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that you can create an interface implementing multiple other interfaces essentially joining them?

Comment: Yes. But then I'm forced to implement every method, than specific one.  I would like to pick implement one and perform operation on it.

Comment: Then do as in Swing and make an adapter with empty implementations for every method.  You then just override the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the packagename in the implementation of the interface.

```
public class interfaces implements package.a.IValidator, package.b.IValidator
```